Make the Right Photo Stitch
I have a bunch of images in an image sequence that I want to make a photo stitch of, but when I put them all together, the photo stitch was crooked and messed up. What tool automatically selects the best images for stitching?
Also, what can I use to make photo stitches out of videos?

What is a "stitch" in your words?

There are several that could be used, but none I know of that can select the "best" photos for stitching automatically.  That's usually down to a human operator.  Most stitching software such as Photoshop or Hugin requires that the photos slightly overlap. If they don't overlap, then the stitching will be messed up, as the software can't calculate where or how to stitch them.
